# Creating Moire-like pattern while avoiding an overly dense center

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to create something similar to the image below. I've tried the rotate and transform each, however that creates a really dark centre (refer to image 2). Any idea how to create image 1, without the dark center?

[image] image 1

[image] image 2

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: When the moon hits your eye... Like a big pizza pie, that's a moire...

Comment: What kind of center you get really depend on the actual anti-aliasing method used. If your method would be perfect it wouldn't actually show up as a problem at all.

Answer (score 6):

Do the same but adding a gradient to the vector stroke

- From 10% of the main color, to main color, to 10% of the main color if it is over white

[image]

[image]

- From the background color, to main color, to 90% of the background color if it is over a background color

[image: COlor]

[image]

- Reducing the side colors opacity if it is over a image:

[image: opacity]

[image: overimage]

Comment: thank you! quick question. how did you manage to swirl your pattern like that? I tried the twist effect and it gave me what I've got in image 2. Thanks again.

Comment: @Tian don't use a twist effect. Rotate a semi-circle instead. You can see the semi-circle that Danielillo started with in his answer.

Comment: Right, is a semicircle rotated and duplicated 3º (120 times) from one of its extreme points.